# Want to change background color by using a string-array on button click

Tags: android

So I have this view, with a textview and a button. At the moment when I click the button the textview gets updated with text from the things_array. I have also made a colorcode_array with several HEX codes. Now what I want is when I press the same button, that the background color must change to one of the HEX codes from colorcode_array.

CODE:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MyActivity2"
android:background="#ffdb4b5e">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="72sp"
    android:background="#00000000"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/thing1"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    />
```

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_activity2);
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Button n = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "BebasNeue Bold.ttf");
    n.setTypeface(typeface);
    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"OSP-DIN.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(face);

final String[] values = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.things_array);
n.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Random RAND=new Random();
    String nextValue = values[RAND.nextInt(values.length)];
    tv.setText(nextValue);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the root view of your layout an id and then use that to find the view and set the background color:

layout.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/layout_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MyActivity2"
                android:background="#ffdb4b5e">
```

onClick:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Random RAND=new Random();
    int position = RAND.nextInt( values.length );
    String nextValue = values[position];
    int colors[] = getResources().getIntArray( R.array.colorcode_array );
    int color = colors[position];

    tv.setText( nextValue );
    View layout = findViewById( R.id.layout_view );
    layout.setBackgroundColor( color );
```

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to set the background color of the textView, I want to set the actual background color of the activity

Comment: That's much better, but the color will now only change to one color no?

Comment: You can define `color` however you want.  Just pull it from the color array before you set it in the `setBackgroundColor` method.

Comment: Did this: layout.setBackgroundColor(R.array.colorcode_array);  . But now the color changes to gray and stays gray at each button click?

Comment: That way will just set the background color to whatever the ID of the array is.  You have to get the color from the array like you get the string from the other array, edited my answer to show an example.

Comment: Hehe, and how do I do that? I am so terribly sorry for my noob knowledge. Have only been programming a few days now

Comment: Added more to my answer.

Comment: Still stays grey, a bit lighter though

Comment: You should probably make a new question with your current code since it's a different issue now.